# Boostrap hide at 480 px

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm complete newb to bootstrap. I have a css class that is working for some of our other sections. I tried to add a new section and its not working. I have no clue what I'm doing lol From what I can see see it should work. It's suppose to collapse if the min width is 480px or less.

HTML:

```
<div class="orderhistory-subcontainer2 orderhistoryhide"><b>Paid</b></div>
```

CSS:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .orderhistoryhide
        {
            display:none;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hello, your class has nothing to do with bootstrap. You are asking a question about media queries... Futhermore, you've writter 'min-width' but you seem to want 'max-width'

Comment: "It's suppose to collapse if the min width is 480px or less"... but you've written your rule to only apply when the width is 480px or **more** (i.e. it will be display:none when the width is _at minimum_ 480px. I think you just got your logic back to front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a partial answer to my question:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .orderhistoryhide
     {
        visibility: hidden;
     }
 }
```

display:none; is not working. I'm not sure why but settings visibility to hidden seems to work now. I think I need to change a few other things in the html as well but this appears to be the correct fix. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If the screen size is `480px` wide or less, hide the element

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
     .orderhistoryhide
         {
            display: none;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Hmm does not appear to work. I believe your code is likely correct but for some reason its not working. I'll post the css maybe I put it in wrong

Comment: can you clear your browser caches? and also check parenthesis as well.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change the min-width to max-width cause

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .orderhistoryhide
        {
            display:none;
        }
}
```

mean that display none will be applied to screens that are wider than 480px
if you want less than 480px

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.orderhistoryhide
    {
        display:none;
    }
```

}